# wsdl2java Error: Emitter failure. Invalid endpoint address in port

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to run the wsdl2java command on a WSDL file that was given to me from another group in my company.  I know wsdl2java works because I can run the examples but when I try it on the wsdl given to me it fails.  The one big difference is that the WSDL given to me uses SSL.

I’m using Java 1.4 (checked it a few time) and made sure all the correct jars are in my class path, jsse.jar is there.

COMMAND: java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java --server-side GenericWebService.wsdl

ERROR:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
**java.io.IOException: Emitter failure.  Invalid endpoint address in port AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_0020_ServiceSoap in service AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_x0020_ServiceLocator: **
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaServiceImplWriter.writeFileBody(JavaServiceImplWriter.ja
a:242)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaWriter.generate(JavaWriter.java:127)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaServiceWriter.generate(JavaServiceWriter.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaGeneratorFactory$Writers.generate(JavaGeneratorFactory.j
va:421)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.generate(Parser.java:476)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.access$000(Parser.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:362)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)

asdf

```
<wsdl:portType name="AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_x0020_ServiceSoap">
  <wsdl:operation name="Provision">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:ProvisionSoapIn" />
    <wsdl:output message="tns:ProvisionSoapOut" />
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_x0020_ServiceSoap" type="tns:AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_x0020_ServiceSoap">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <wsdl:operation name="Provision">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://xmlns.fmr.com/systems/dev/aar/2008/05/GenericWebService/Provision" style="document" />
    <wsdl:input>
      <soap:body use="literal" />
      <soap:header message="tns:ProvisionServiceProcessingDirectives" part="ServiceProcessingDirectives" use="literal" />
      <soap:header message="tns:ProvisionServiceCallContext" part="ServiceCallContext" use="literal" />
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
      <soap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>


<wsdl:service name="AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_x0020_Service">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Generic web service definition for provisioning requests callable by AccessCENTRAL</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:port name="AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_x0020_ServiceSoap" binding="tns:AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_x0020_ServiceSoap">
    <soap:address location="" />
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**
The problem was that the parser needed a value in the <soap:address location="" /> for it to complete.  I added the URL of my service and it worked.
New Lines looked like:

```
<soap:address location="" http://localhost:8080/axis/services/AC_x0020_Generic_x0020_Web_x0020_Service" />
```

Comment: Please post the portion of the WSDL with the <port> elements.

Comment: Do you need more code than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **location** specified by the **soap:address** is blank.  It should be the URI of the SOAP service.  See [soap:address](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap:address).

Looking at soapAction, *http://xmlns.fmr.com/systems/dev/aar/2008/05/GenericWebService* might be the correct value for location.